# Probability of $X > Y$ given that $X, Y$ are i.i.d. continuous r.v.s

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Can someone please explain why is $P(X > Y) = \frac{1}{2}$, when $X, Y$ are i.i.d. continuous random variables? I have seen people use the symmetry argument to justify this answer. The argument goes as follows: there are two ways of arranging two numbers $x$ and $y$, and out of these arrangements only one has $x > y$. So, the probability using symmetry is $0.5$.

I don't understand this conclusion. Doesn't this argument make an assumption that the values of $X$ and $Y$ that are drawn are not equal? To take a more concrete example, if we assume $X, Y$ are standard normal, wouldn't the sample space be divided into three events: $X > Y, X < Y, X = Y$? Based on this, we can say that $X > Y$ and $X < Y$ must be equal using symmetry, and let's call this value $\alpha$. So,

$2\alpha + P(X=Y) = 1$.

Clearly, $\alpha < 0.5$, contrary to the first argument. So, which is the correct argument and why?

Edit: based on the comments I am adding the calculations for $X=Y$ in case of normal distributions. Can someone point out the mistake? Thanks!

$P(X=Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(X=Y|Y=y) P(Y=y) dy$

$P(X=Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-y^{2}} dy$

$P(X=Y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt\pi}$.

Intuitively, the symmetry argument feels like an approximation (probably a very good one). Imagine we have a bivariate normal distribution, which is formed using $X$ and $Y$. $P(X>Y)$ represents the region below the line $X=Y$ (in the 1st quadrant). Similarly, we can argue about the values in the other 3 quadrants. By geometry, the area of line is zero (because the line has no width?), and hence you arrive at the 1D analogy that the probability it takes a specific value is zero. Still not sure though why it doesn't show up in the calculations above.

Edit: I realize the mistake I made in the above calculations. Going from step 1 to step 2, when I replaced $P(X=Y|Y=y)$ with $f_{X}(y)$, this is wrong. As pointed out in the comments and answer below, this must be equal to zero. I confused (/abused) the notation for the discrete and continuous cases. Thanks everyone for an interesting discussion.

Comment: Are we talking about continuous or discrete random variables?

Comment: The point is the probability that two continuous random variables assume the same value is $0$ which gives $\alpha = 1/2$. Had they been discrete, then yes one would very much need to account for that probability.

Comment: The probability of $X=Y$ is $0$, if $X, Y$ are $\underline{\textrm{continuous}}$ r.v.´s : $P(X=Y)=0$

Comment: I am talking about continuous random variables.

Comment: Let $X,Y$ two continuous random variables on $\mathbb R$. Then $X=Y$ implies $X-Y=0$. If $Z=X-Y$ then $Z$ is continuous as well. And therefore $P(Z=0)=0$.

Comment: @sudeep5221: Feel free to expand that comment into an answer

Comment: Your $\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}$ is maybe the pdf, but the probability is still $P(X=Y)=0$

Comment: @callculus I am not sure I understand your comment. If pdf is non-zero, wouldn't there be a non-zero probability associated because a pdf >=0. Also, I don't think this represents the pdf. I am just using the Law of Total Probability to partition the sample space on all possible values of Y, and using that finding the probability of the event. Clearly, this is not a pdf, rather the probability of the event (summed over all possible values of the event).

Comment: If a random variable $X$ is continuous, then the probability that this random variable take on a specific value $c$ is  $0$. Have a look a the normal distribution, exponential distribution, ...

Comment: Just to complete the previous coments: in general we have the equality of events $(X=x)=(X\leq x)\setminus (X<x)$, so $P(X=x)=F(x)-F(x-)$, $F$ being the cdf of $X$. If $F$ is a continuous function (this is the case for any continuous rv), then $F(x)=F(x-)$ and $P(X=x)=0$. Then if $Y,X$ are continuous iid $P(X=Y)=E[1_{X=Y}]=\int P(X=x,Y=x)dF(x,y)=0$. So as @callculus pointed out, for the gaussian rv $P(X=Y)=0$.

Comment: The random variable $Z=X-Y$ is normally distributed as well. Therefore $f_Z(z)=...$ is the pdf of that random variable, which is continuous. Thus $P(Z=c)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of $X-Y$ is symmetric around zero, that is $\mathsf{P}(X-Y\le v)=\mathsf{P}(Y-X\le v)$ for all $v\in \mathbb{R}$ (for example, you may show that the characteristic function of $X-Y$ and $Y-X$ are equal, i.e. $\varphi_{X-Y}(t)=\varphi_{Y-X}(t)=\varphi_X(t)\varphi_X(-t)$). Then as you noticed
$$
\mathsf{P}(X-Y>0)+\mathsf{P}(Y-X>0)+\mathsf{P}(X-Y=0)=1,
$$
and the result follows assuming that $\mathsf{P}(X-Y=0)=0$. (This is always true for continuous r.v.s.)

Answer (score 3):

Another perspective (using measure-theoretic probability): 
$$P(X > Y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X > y)dF(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (1 - F(y))dF(y) = 1 - \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(y)dF(y) = 1/2.$$

Literally, we can evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(y)dF(y) = \int_0^1 zdz = 1/2$ given $F$ is continuous. A more rigorous proof for it rests on Fubini's theorem. Interested people may refer to Theorem $18.4$ of *Probability and Measure* by *Patrick Billingsley*.